# Android ADT Plugin doesn't show up in Eclipse

Tags: android, windows-7, eclipse-plugin, preferences, adt

I'm using Windows 7 and installed the 64 bit version of Eclipse 3.5.2.  I then installed the Android ADT plugin, but when I try to configure it in the Windows > Preferences dialog, the Android Plugin doesn't show up in the left pane.  Instead I see DDMS.  This prevents me from specifying the location of the Android SDK (unless there is another way) to give me the appropriate templates and such.

Someone posted a fix to this that includes setting the permissions of Eclipse, but that didn't work for me.  I tried installing the Android Plugin from both online installation (thru the URL install) and the offline Archive method.

Comment: Hi, I have similar problem too, in my case I can't even see the DDMS in Preferences dialog's left panel. I am using Windows Vista SP2 32-bit, Galileo 3.5.0.I20090611-1540, JRE build 1.6.0_21-b07, and ADT 0.9.8.v201008281755-53891. Mind to share the permission fix you found?

Comment: I just retry by removing/reinstalling everything, now able to see the Android entry appears in the left panel.

Answer (score 15):

If you're running Windows Vista or 7, make sure you right-click Eclipse and RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR. I literally spent six hours figuring this out, and this was what fixed it.

Comment: your answer proved to be by far the most helpful of all answers I received so far to the problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527903/huh-android-preferences-page-refuses-to-load-after-adding-sdk-1-6 . In fact, it was **THE** solution (workaround actually) to the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I up-voted you and I thought I would add that using Linux (ubuntu for me) I had a "Duh" moment after reading your post...Start ./android as root.. $sudo ./android ...so Thanks so much for your post, it even translated to Linux...spent many minutes on this myself.

Comment: I am having exactly same issue on mac osx Lion.......... how do i solve this on mac? I tried `sudo /Applications/eclipse/eclipse` - doesn't help

Answer (score 7):

Dear people from the future:

I had roughly the same problem in **linux**, except that i didn't see anything at all but vanilla eclipse after installing. by combining both previous answers i got it to work:

start eclipse with **sudo eclipse -clean**, install the plugins and restart eclipse. the plugins showed up including the welcome screen that's supposed to be there.

after that it should work when running as regular user as well.

works for both the android sdk and the gwt sdk. (and probably other eclipse plugins)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the plugin, then restart as follows:

**eclipse -clean**

Now try reinstalling the ADT from the online installation

Answer (score 0):

For users having similar problem and not luck with other solutions:

I have windows XP but had same problem. I realized that I had JDK5/bin folder in my PATH environment variable (though my JDK_HOME was pointing to JDK6), as soon as I modified the PATH to replace bin of JDK5 with JDK6, the Android buttons on eclipse (after restart with -clean) along with Android option in Preferences & New Project showed up. (Weird eh!)

Also, consider to install the bundle android installation having eclipse with pre-configured Android SDK if a new eclipse installation doesn't matter to you

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

Answer (score 0):

The above answers do not confront the heart of the problem. There is a feature in Windows 7 that prevents downloaded files from direct access of local files.  All of the state is perfectly maintained in the Eclipse workspace instance. The problem is easily resolved by doing the following:

1. Find the "Eclipse" executable
2. Right-click on it.
3. Click "Properties".
4. Select the "General" tab.
5. Look for -> Security: "This file came from another computer and might be blocked..."
6. Click Unblock.

This is a much better solution than uninstalling and reinstalling the ADT or Eclipse which can be a pain.