# Eclipse is not recognizing that the ADT plugin for android development is intalled

Tags: android

I'm having a lot of problems trying to get eclipse to recognize that the ADT plugin was installed, which refers to the android development kit.

When I try to go to windows-preferences, nothing related to android appears.  If I try to start a new project, android is not an option.

I've read through this page: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html and am still having issues.

Things I've tried:
1. Re-installing eclipse, then re-installing the plugin
2. running eclipse -clean
3. running eclipse as an administrator
4. everything listed here [Android ADT Plugin doesn't show up in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723450/android-adt-plugin-doesnt-show-up-in-eclipse)

Comment: This may also be answered by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691009/eclipse-indigo-android-adt-install-ok-no-android-option-in-preferences-and/9542700#9542700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I had trouble installing the plugin with the secure site https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

I had to use the regular http link  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/