# ADT plugin doesn't show up in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I've followed the instruction [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) for installing ADT, but I don't see any sign of ADT in Eclipse, except that it's installed.

According to what it says [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#create), I should have additional project templates, which are missing. See the screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what all project options you see under file->new->others? if adt is installed you should see a option for android project there.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing with my Eclipse.  I'm just going to port over to Android Studio.. I'm so F***'n tired of Eclipse and the hoops I've got to jump through just about every month.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides reinstalling eclipse and reloading the ADT I have found another solution :

Inside Eclipse ->Window ->Customize Perspective ->Command Groups Availability ->Check All Android groups -> OK

That should solve any issues. Currently there are four (4) android groups.

Good luck guys!

Answer (score 5):

You Simply need to Download the ADT Plugin. Please look at step by step guide [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing).

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....
2. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location: 
   `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
4. Click OK 
   Note: If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).
5. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
6. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
7. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.

   **Note:** If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
8. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Comment: He did all that...look at his first screenshot.

Comment: But it may be a problem of improper installation, i would suggest you to remove the plugins and re-install it.

Comment: @Android except for consuming time I don't believe it's gonna help but I'll give it a shot. Anyway, I understand from your profile that you are of the Android Dev team, it's really a shame there is no one click installation. You should learn from Microsoft on this aspect.

Comment: @Android I reinstalled and everything is as before.

Comment: Its very Simple, go to Help Menu--> Install New Software Option, there will be a link in the coming Dialogbox "What is Already Installed" , above the "Next" Button. Click on it, it will show you the installed plug-ins, then select the DDMS plugin- and click on "Uninstall" ...

Answer (score 3):

I'm on **Ubuntu** and had the same problem as the poster. Had to run Eclipse as `sudo` and do the ADT install (into the same workspace as my non-root user account).

Restarted Eclipse as a non-root user and everything works.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to update JDK.
Please check JDK version.

```
#java -version
```

I've meet same problem when I use JDK 1.5 on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here: [Android ADT Plugin doesn't show up in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723450/android-adt-plugin-doesnt-show-up-in-eclipse)

Actually, running as administrator on Win7 worked for me after uninstalling ADT.

Another thing is to execute eclipse with the parameter -clean after uninstalling ADT.

Answer (score 1):

When you load the Android ADT plugins, using Help -> Install New Software, you need to have started Eclipse with "run as administrator". If you installed the ADT plugins without having run Eclipse as administrator, it might not work when you go to Windows -> Preferences...., and Android doesn't appear in the left panel.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have the latest jdk installed. that was the issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, your installation didn't register properly. Try removing ADT and reinstalling it.

To uninstall, go to Window > Preferences > Install/Upload, then click on the "Uninstall or update" link. Find ADT (and related software), remove, then try to reinstall.

Comment: I did that and everything is as before.

Comment: Indigo, now deleting and reinstalling eclipse

Comment: Only other thing I can think to try would be uninstalling, close Eclipse, run Eclipse as Administrator, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall Eclipse and that solved the problem.